# stripe webhook event not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to send an email after a customer has signup to a plan

I have set up the webhook in stripe but its not sending the email

What have i done wrong, here is the webhook file

```
<?php

require 'core/lib/Stripe.php';

Stripe::setApiKey("YOUR_SECRET_KEY");

// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);

// for extra security, retrieve from the Stripe API
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);

// This will send receipts on successful charges
if ($event_json->type == 'charge.succeeded') {

    $To = 'myemail@email.com'; 
    $Subject = 'Stripe Message'; 
    $Message = 'Webhook worked'; 
    $Headers = "From: coolio@yahoo.com \r\n" . 
    "Reply-To: coolio@yahoo.com \r\n" . 
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
    mail($To, $Subject, $Message, $Headers);

}

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
?>
```

When i look in the events in Stripe, its not showing any response

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to obtain the event from Stripe to test validity and handle exceptions (note that this intentionally fails with test webhooks):

```
try {
    // Check against Stripe to confirm that the ID is valid
    $event_id = $event_json->id;
    $event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);
}
catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
    // If the event is invalid, log an error
    error_log($e->getMessage(),0);
}
```

Then you should be able to obtain the event type property from  like so:

```
    if (isset($event) && $event->type == "charge.succeeded") {
      // Send your email
    }
```